# sql how to get top 5 from the count of a join per user

Tags: sql

This is the SQL code I have so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER(), users.*
FROM items
LEFT JOIN users
ON items.user_id = users.id
ORDER BY COUNT
LIMIT 5
```

I have 2 tables. `Users` and `Items`. `Users` can have many `Items`. I am trying to find which user has the most items and return the top few.

Thank you!

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.  Your title and your question are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following, using a sub-select to get the count of the items per user:

```
SELECT u.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE items.user_id = u.user_id) AS cnt
FROM users u
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 5
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6b80579d3fe2e94543c52413f77f1e8)

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to find which user has the most items and return the top few [items, presumably].

You can return all the items for the user with the most by using window functions:

```
select i.*
from (select i.*, max(cnt) over () as max_cnt
      from (select i.*,
                   count(*) over (partition by user_id) as cnt
            from items i
           ) i
     ) i
where cnt = max_cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a sub-query:

```
select * 
from (SELECT COUNT(i.user_id) cnt
             , u.*
      FROM users u
      LEFT JOIN Items i
      ON u.id = i.user_id
      group by id, name) A
order by cnt desc
LIMIT 5
```

**NOTE**:

Do not forget to put **DESC** in your order by clause because of:

> how to get top 5 from the count of a join per user

**Explanation**:

Letter `A` is only an alias of the sub-query. You can name it what ever you want.

**DEMO**:

[Here is a small demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7dfd45ba661595201f9494d0baebfd89)